# How to make <a> tag link correspond to a certain timestamp in an embedded youtube video (without refreshing the video)

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, anchor

I have a video embedded on a website, and I'm trying to make an  tag link skip to a certain timestamp in the video when it is clicked. Right now, I have a line of javascript doing this for the youtube video.

```
<iframe id="videoPlayer" class="lssiframevideo" title="video" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media;" allowfullscreen 
src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/VsnfaqwjE04?autoplay=0&controls=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&start=0"></iframe>

<div class = "bottomtextcol">
    <a href="#" onclick="changeVideo('video1')">0:30</a> Stamp A 
</div>
<div class = "bottomtextcol">
    <a href="#" onclick="changeVideo('video2')">0:45<a> Stamp B 
</div>
<div class = "bottomtextcol">
    <a href="#" onclick="changeVideo('video3')">1:10<a> Stamp C 
</div>
```

```
function changeVideo(videoId) 
{
    var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
    if (videoId === 'video1') 
    {
        videoPlayer.src = 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/VHnfwqhjE04?autoplay=1&controls=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&start=30'
    } 
    else if (videoId === 'video2') 
    {
        videoPlayer.src = 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/VHnfwqhjE04?autoplay=1&controls=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&start=45'
    }
    else if (videoId === 'video3') 
    {
        videoPlayer.src = 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/VHnfwqhjE04?autoplay=1&controls=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&start=70'
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make it so clicking the link does not reload the video?

Comment: `start=30` should work, what's the problem?

Comment: that keeps the youtube video from reloading?

Comment: It can't prevent the reload, the browser has no way of knowing it's the same video.